# Auto allow access to MacOS accessibility API during development

Tags: xcode, macos

I'm developing an app that uses the accessibility api. Every time I make a change and rebuild I have to remove and re-add the app to the "Security and Privacy / Accessibility" view below. This gets pretty annoying after a while.

Is there any way to disable this security check while developing or make the setting stick even though the app itself is changing?

[image: Security and privacy / accessibility settings]

Comment: I can't figure this out either and it's driving me nuts.

Comment: Think I may have figured it out after all: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72312351/persist-accessibility-permissions-between-builds-in-xcode-13/72312500#72312500